# Play a sound after every command finishes in iTerm

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I would like to play a sound every time iTerm 2 finishes a command. Shell I use is `-zsh` I.e. when I enter

```
sleep 30
```

I would like it to play a sound, so I would know that the command has finished
All the solutions I've found suggest using something like

```
sleep 30 ; say "done"
```

That works, but I don't want to write say "done" after every command - instead I'd like it to play the sound after every command.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the shell? Please respond by [edit]ing and adding information to the body of the question.